# Cannot convert from type object to long

Tags: java, casting, types, long-integer

I have a hashtable named `table`. The type value is `long`. I am getting values using `.values()`. Now I want to access these values.

```
Collection val = table.values();

Iterator itr = val.iterator();
long a  =   (long)itr.next();
```

But when I try to get it, it gives me error because I can't convert from type `object` to `long`. How can I go around it?

Comment: the type in the Hashtable cannot be long -- you must mean Long.

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

```
  Long a = (Long)itr.next();
```

You end up with a Long object but with autoboxing you may use it almost like a primitive long.

Another option is to use Generics:

```
  Iterator<Long> itr = val.iterator();
  Long a = itr.next();
```

Answer (score 7):

`Number` class can be used for to overcome numeric data-type casting.

In this case the following code might be used:

```
long a = ((Number)itr.next()).longValue();
```

I've prepared the examples below:
`Object` **to** `long` **example - 1**

```
// preparing the example variables
Long l = new Long("1416313200307");
Object o = l;

// Long casting from an object by using `Number` class
System.out.print(((Number) o).longValue() );
```

Console **output** would be:

```
1416313200307
```

`Object` **to** `double` **example - 2**

```
// preparing the example variables
double d = 0.11;
Object o = d;

// Double casting from an Object -that's a float number- by using `Number` class
System.out.print(((Number) o).doubleValue() + "\n");
```

Console **output** would be:

```
0.11
```

`Object` **to** `double` **example - 3** 
Be careful about this **simple mistake**! If a float value is converted by using `doubleValue()` function, the first value might not be equal to final value. 
 
As shown below `0.11` != `0.10999999940395355`.

```
// preparing the example variables
float f = 0.11f;
Object o = f;

// Double casting from an Object -that's a float number- by using `Number` class
System.out.print(((Number) o).doubleValue() + "\n");
```

Console **output** would be:

```
0.10999999940395355
```

`Object` **to** `float` **example - 4**

```
// preparing the example variables
double f = 0.11;
Object o = f;

// Double casting from an Object -that's a float number- by using `Number` class
System.out.print(((Number) o).floatValue() + "\n");
```

Console **output** would be:

```
0.11
```

Answer (score 4):

Try : `long a = ((Long) itr.next()).longValue();`

Comment: This is more long-winded than it needs to be - see the other answer which refers to autoboxing.

Comment: @crazyscot: From OP's code I assumed he's using an older version of Java than Java 5.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the *new* **Generics** features from Java 5.

> When you take an element out of a
>   Collection, you must cast it to the
>   type of element that is stored in the
>   collection. **Besides being
>   inconvenient, this is unsafe**. The
>   compiler does not check that your cast
>   is the same as the collection's type,
>   so the cast can fail at run time.
>
> Generics provides a way for you to
>   communicate the type of a collection
>   to the compiler, so that it can be
>   checked. Once the compiler knows the
>   element type of the collection, the
>   compiler can check that you have used
>   the collection consistently and can
>   insert the correct casts on values
>   being taken out of the collection.

You can read this quick [howto](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) or this more complete [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

in my case I have an array of Objects that I get from a flex client,

sometimes the numbers can be interpreted by java as int and sometimes as long,

so to resolve the issue i use the 'toString()' function as follows:

```
public Object run(Object... args) {

  final long uid = Long.valueOf(args[0].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long value = Long.parseLong((String)request.getAttribute(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but while doing JSP coding. The above mentioned suggestions regarding Long and generics either did not work or did not fit into the code fragment.

I had to solve it like this(in JSP):

```
<%Object y=itr.next(); %>
```

and afterwards use my Object y like <%=y%> as we would use any other Java variable in scriptlet.