# java getClass show String but variable is affected in a long object

Tags: java, arrays, string, casting

This simple line of code is giving me a headache :

```
Set<Long> statutList = rechercheSalarieForm.getIdStatutList();
```

`getIdStatutList()` is returning a set of Longs

BUT when I do :

```
statutList.toArray()[0].getClass()
```

or

```
rechercheSalarieForm.getIdStatutList().toArray()[0].getClass()
```

The result is :

```
(java.lang.Class<T>) class java.lang.String
```

This statutList is send straight to DAO layer which doesn't like Strings in the hibernate request.

How is it possible to have Strings in a Long array ?

Edit :

Short program :

```
public List<EffectifRupHistoriqueExtractionVO>   
generateExtractionRupHistorique(RechercheSalariesRupFormVO rechercheSalarieForm) throws       FunctionalException {

    Collection<Long> statutList = rechercheSalarieForm.getIdStatutList();
    // Some business/Dao call with statutList in parameter
}
```

Object RechercheSalariesRupFormVO :

```
public class RechercheSalariesRupFormVO extends ValueObject{
// some declaration
    private Set<Long> idStatutList;
    public Set<Long> getIdStatutList() {
        return idStatutList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a short but complete program? What is the *actual* type used by `getIdStatutList`?

Comment: The only possilbity is that getIdStatutList() returns unchecked types and you are converting that in to Set<Long>. You will see warning in such scenario.

Comment: Check the class of an element of `idStatutList` before returning it (in `getIdStatutList()`). To see whether it 1) has indeed the correct values and 2) that you are actually calling that method and not some other (similar) one.

Comment: We need to see a **complete** program. The code you posted is by no means complete. We can't run it and it will not reproduce this.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : i can't produce a "short" program, there is 4 layers involved. The IHM layer sending RechercheSalariesRupFormVO is in Flex

Comment: Just because there are 4 layers involved in the *real* code doesn't mean that there have to be 4 layers involved to reproduce the problem. Part of your job in diagnosing the issue is to isolate it as far as possible.

Comment: @Veger idStatutlist from rechercheSalarieForm is a java.lang.Object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work arround (it's ugly) :

```
int size = rechercheSalarieForm.getIdStatutList().size();
Collection<Long> statutList = new ArrayList<Long>();
int i=0;
for (i = 0; i < size ; i++) {               
    statutList.add(Long.valueOf(rechercheSalarieForm.getIdStatutList().toArray()[i].toString()));
}
```

Thanks to him : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12881094/2369897

if anyone know the why ...